# ddSlick in ASP.net when dropdown autopostback not works

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to user ddSlick, in a ASP.NET project, to make a dropdownlist with images, but when i user the ddSlick to make the dropdownn "beautifull", it loses the autopostback and not run the OnSelectedIndexChanged method.

Does any one resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Comment: What does this mean: _"but when i user the ddSlick to make the dropdownn "beautifull""_?? Even if english is not your native language you could make more of an effort.

Comment: please show me your code

Comment: Hello Tim, it means that when I execute the javascript to transform the dropdownlist into the ddSlick, so I called it beautifull ;). Do you know how to help me?

Comment: <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddLanguageSelector" CssClass="LanguageSelector" AutoPostBack="True" onchange="javascript:if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == 'More'){ showMoreLanguages(); return false; }" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddLanguageSelector_SelectedIndexChanged" meta:resourcekey="ddLanguageSelectorResource" />
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    try {
        $("header div.Wrapper div.HeaderUserAccess select.LanguageSelector").ddslick({
            onSelected: function (data){
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
});

Comment: I think you just remove return false; in onchange event.It may work.

Comment: The return false is ok... I need it dor for other javascript functions, as if when selected one option, i do not want to execute the postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that because I used the functionality of the control asp:DropdownList, when the control is rendered with the ddSlick, it just disapears and the functionality just gone...
So I found another control that works and keeps the functionality of the `asp:DropdownList` working as untouched, the control is the `ms-Dropdown`.
I let you with the links bellow:

- http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown
- https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You are using onchange event which is client side event then you set AutoPostBack="False" and set Clientidmode="static".You need to exclude OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddLanguageSelector_SelectedIndexChanged" this code and code behind event also.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks in advance to all you that see this question, and answered it, and commented it.
I see that because I used the functionality of the control asp:DropdownList, when the control is rendered with the ddSlick, it just disapears and the functionalitys just gone...
So I found another control that works and keeps the functionalitis of the asp:DropdownList working as untouched, the control is the ms-Dropdown.
I let you with the links above:

 - http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown
 - https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown

Thanks for all good support.